# What does 0x0a stand for, if used in a query?

Tags: mysql

```
‘ union select null,concat(table_name,0x0a,column_name) 

from information_schema.columns where table_name= ‘users’#
```

I'm wondering what 0x0a, in the above statement, stands for .

Thanks a lot

Comment: do I really need that..I mean if I get rid of it does the query work the same?

Comment: from thecode you posted one cannot tell if neccessary or not

Comment: How are we to know whether you need it? It's _your_ query and _your_ data, so you tell us!

Comment: You should not use Word as a code editor

Comment: hehe someones doing SQLi here, otherwise that statement wouldnt make sense, the OP is querying MySQL metatables, specifically information_schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can all be derived from documentation.

The result of the pseudo-column `CONCAT(table_name,0x0a,column_name)` will be, for each row, the value of `table_name`, [concatenated](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)<sup>1</sup> to the *line feed* character (hexadecimal<sup>2</sup> 0x0A, decimal 10, or `LF`), concatenated to the value of `column_name`.

That is, you'll see the value of `table_name`, then `column_name` on a line visually "underneath" it, for each row of data:

```
+------------+---------------+---------------------------------------+
| table_name |  column_name  |  CONCAT(table_name,0x0a,column_name)  |
+------------+---------------+---------------------------------------+
|     a      |       b       |                   a                   |
|            |               |                   b                   |
+------------+---------------+---------------------------------------+
|     c      |       d       |                   c                   |
|            |               |                   d                   |
+------------+---------------+---------------------------------------+
|     e      |       f       |                   e                   |
|            |               |                   f                   |
+------------+---------------+---------------------------------------+
```

Only you can possibly know whether you "need" this, but it does seem unusual. Typically you'd simply include `table_name` and `column_name` independently in your result set and do presentation/formatting elsewhere.

```
SELECT table_name, column_name
```

Also, `table_name` and `column_name` are both quite confusing names for columns in tables. However, it may be relevant if you are selecting data from a MySQL metatable which contains information about other tables.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> [string concatenation is the operation of joining two character strings end-to-end](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenation)</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup> [hexadecimal (also base 16, or hex) is a positional numeral system with a radix, or base, of 16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal)</sup>

Comment: How did you create this "ascii-style table"? Did you type every char by itself or is there a tool or something for doing this?

Comment: It's just a few spaces, hyphens, "plus" signs and pipes. All symbols readily available on my keyboard. Hardly rocket science!

Comment: I doubt that you wrote it by hand.

Answer (score 1):

0x0A is equal to decimal 10 (ten). This is equal to the ASCII code for LF (Line Feed), which is a newline on many systems. Depending on your type, it is the *number* `10` or the *character* LF.

Answer (score 0):

It will show table_name and below the column_name of the table "users", probably for each column:

```
users
----------
col1
col2
```

Comment: Yes, it prints the column name on the next row (i.e. a newline)